# Multiple DHCP Servers maintain multiple LOGICAL subnets

Tags: dhcp-server

I have one physical LAN, but I have several distinct groups and each should have their own subnet. What this means is each server should be able to recognize its own clients and ignore the rest. Obviously this could be done with MAC addresses, but that sort of defeats the purpose. I remember something about Vendor Arguments/Parameters/Variables/Classes and think this the way to do it, but I can't find any advice. I think the discipline is to identify each client as a member of, say "Class 1", or "Lab", or "Sales", and these classes identify the scope that the DHCP server configures for that client.

Any advice?

Thanks for the help,

Chris.

Comment: Is each group on their own VLAN?

Comment: If by "VLAN" you mean some appliance segregated subset of the LAN, then no. Everybody is on the same set of wires. The intent is that there are different groups and they should each have a parochial view of the world, meaning seeing only the peers and resources pertinent to their mission. Shared resources will be implemented by multi-homed servers that can span subnets.

Comment: As Jim G has said below, you should really setup VLANs for each group. It's really the only way to do what you want with the DHCP services.

Answer (score 1):

VLANs would be the proper way to do this.  It sounds like you have all of the DHCP servers and clients in one broadcast domain - no bueno.

Could you explain what you're trying to accomplish by doing this?  That might help determine the best solution.